# How to recoup the renovations to home inherited with my two siblings

Tags: real-estate

In 2016 I along with my two siblings inherited the parental home.  In Aug. 2017 I paid remaining balance of mortgage and invested 30k in renovations to the exterior of the home.  My brother who my mom named as executor of the Will did not probate it.  Fast forward to 2022 the siblings have now decided they want to sell the inherited home.  Even though I paid the mortgage off and did the renovations they now want to charge me rent and do not want to pay 1/3 each for the renovation.  The executor has not told the attorney of the paid in full mortgage nor the renovation.  I do not have money for an attorney.  Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've been living there since 2016? Have they been living there?

Comment: This is a better question for the law stack than the personal finance stack, I suspect, especially since you reference not being able to afford an attorney.

Comment: Seems like you can't afford *not* to get an attorney here...

Comment: "The executor has not told the attorney" - do you know who this attorney is? Is there anything preventing you from contacting them yourself? Unless the attorney is acting as the executor's personal attorney, they should be rendering services to the deceased estate, and acing on behalf of the estate, not the executor. Of course they'd presumably take the executor's word as true by default, but any new information you provide which might contradict or shed new light on the executor's words or actions *should* be taken into account by the attorney.

Comment: I do have the name, however he is working for the executor and not the estate.